# can relative path access more than one level?

Tags: command-line, directory, paths

I'm new to Linux and was wondering if relative path can access more than one level.

For example:

```
/home/john/Desktop/Myfiles/text.txt
```

If i'm currently at `~/` can i jump to `text.txt` without having to write `Desktop/Myfiles/` in my path ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all paths can have multiple components. "Relative" paths don't begin with "`/`", and start looking in the current directory. "Absolute" paths begin with "`/`" and start looking at the root of the filesystem tree, also called "`/`".

So, you can use paths like this:

```
cd $HOME
ls Desktop/MyFiles/text.txt
```

or:

```
cd $HOME/Desktop/MyFiles
ls text.txt
```

In either case, `ls /etc/passwd` would refer to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Skipping parts of path cannot be done, that is you cannot do something like  `cd ~/.../Myfiles` . Suppose you have `/home/john/Desktop/Myfiles/` and `/home/john/Documents/Myfiles`. When you want to navigate to `Myfiles`, which one do you mean ? One in `~/Desktop` or `~/Documents`. Essential reason is because directory structure is organized into a tree, where each preceding element has to have a parent item. Thus, the question becomes who is the parent directory of `Myfiles` when there are two of them ?

However, there are several things that help navigating the long pathnames:

- save absolute path to variable. Say `myfiles=/home/john/Desktop/Myfiles`. When you start the shell, you already have `$HOME` special variable or you can use tilde expansion `cd ~/Desktop/Myfiles`
- use `pushd` and `popd`. Shell has something known as "directory stack", which can be used to record a sequence of directories. For example, if I do

  ```
  $ pushd /etc
  /etc ~

  $ pushd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/
  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight /etc ~

  $ pushd .
  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight /etc ~
  ```

  Notice that in dirstack the very first item indicates current working directory, while the second item remains unchanged even if you `cd` elsewhere. This is why `pushd .` was added. Now, if we navigate elsewhere, `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight` will be stored on the stack and we can always return to it.

  ```
  # navigate elsewhere after pushd .
  $ cd /var/log
  $ cd /usr/share
  # check what's in the stack
  $ echo ${DIRSTACK[@]}
  /usr/share /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight /etc /home/ubuntuadmin
  # go to one of the directories on the stack
  $ cd ${DIRSTACK[1]}
  $ pwd
  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight
  # remember that very first item changes, it's the current working directory
  $ echo ${DIRSTACK[@]}
  /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight /etc /home/ubuntuadmin
  ```
- Use symlinks.Example:

  ```
  $ ln -s /var/log ~/logs
  $ cd ~/logs
  ```

  Now instead of doing `cd /var/log` you can do `cd ~/logs`. Trivial example, but imagine if `/var/log` was something like `/media/external_harddrive/someproject/subproject/data/bignumbers/calculations/` . We can just do `cd ~/calculations` then if we have symlink. Of course disadvantage of symlinks is that when directory is renamed or removed, symlink remains and becomes broken, but it's a simple fix - either re-create full path to symlink or remove the symlink and create new one. We can also create a symlink that points to symlink that points to actual directory, but beware that Linux kernel caps too many levels of symlinks ( and you'd get an error that says exactly that) if there are more than [40 symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53107/85039).

  If the goal is to create a fast way of opening the file `text.txt` the symlink approach can help us with that

  ```
  $ echo 'Hello, this is a test' > ~/Documents/another_directory/file.txt
  $ ln -s ~/Documents/another_directory/file.txt ~/file.symlink
  $ cat ~/file.symlink 
  Hello, this is a test
  $
  ```
- You can use inode numbers. This is often used to deal with difficult filenames, where quoting and special characters become a problem. For instance, if we know directory's inode

  ```
  # return $HOME
  $ cd
  # find the inode
  $ ls -id  ~/Documents/things
  1205421 /home/ubuntuadmin/Documents/things
  # go to the directory by inode
  $ cd "$(find -inum 1205421)"
  $ pwd
  /home/ubuntuadmin/Documents/things
  ```

  Problem with this approach - it is slow and inefficient, since recursive traversal via `find` and checking all inodes along the way requires time and a lot of syscalls.

Comment: Ah it makes sense...so no matter where i am, skipping parts of path is not possible...Thx

Comment: @Anhtu  Essentially yes. If you know there's no duplicate, you could do `cd ~/*/Myfiles` but if there's `~/anotherdir/Myfiles` that approach will fail

Comment: @Anhtu I've added another bullet point, which can be sort of "skipping" but it is slow, inefficient, and essentially is something that goes against Unix/Linux design, so it is used in only special cases - not generally